# Clojure - why is the "do" statement necessary for grouping?

Tags: clojure

I understand that a **do** block will execute statements in sequence and return the value of the last one. I'd *thought* that if I didn't need the return value the do would be unnecessary. Not considering the return value, then, I don't understand the different behavior of these 2 functions:

with "do":

```
(defn x [] 
  (if true 
     (do (println "a") (println "b"))))

=> (x) 
a
b
nil
```

without "do":

```
(defn x [] 
  (if true 
     ((println "a") (println "b"))))

=> (x) 
a
b
NullPointerException   user/x (NO_SOURCE_FILE:3)
```

What is the cause of the NullPointer in the second example?

Comment: As an aside -- it's a horrible, awful practice, and I'm ashamed at myself for mentioning it, but: `(if true [(println "a") (println "b")])` would do something substantially similar to what you're looking for (evaluating each element of the vector during its construction, thus enacting side effects); since this isn't function-call syntax, no null-pointer exception occurs.

Comment: I"m fine with not being able to write it the wrong way - just wanted to be clear on why it was behaving that way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for that comment, including the preface.  Everyone enjoys deeper understanding, even if by way of an illustration of "horrible, awful" tricks.  Yes, cool.  I'll never use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

```
(function argument)
```

...is function-call syntax,

```
((println "a") (println "b"))
```

...expects `(println "a")` to return a function, which it can call with the result of `(println "b")` passed as its first argument.

Instead, `(println "a")` has no return value (returns nil, aka null), and trying to call this null value as a function gives you your NullPointerException.

---

By the way, the idiomatic thing to do here would be to replace your `if` with a `when`, which will expand to implicitly include a `do`:

```
(defn x [] 
  (when true 
     (println "a")
     (println "b")))
```

Comment: Thanks - that was driving me crazy.